# wamp server doesn't go online

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp

I worked with Wamp Server for my work . today I manipulate httpd.config for connect directly to the directory. since I removed this line , wamp server doesn't go online , after I change to previous state and restart wamp , it's still offline. I use Windows 7 and Apache version 2.4.7

```
<Directory C:\wamp\www\Zend\workspaces\test\public>

DirectoryIndex index.php

AllowOverride All

Order allow,deny

Allow from all

</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try that ?

DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/Zend/workspaces"
    ServerName local-portail.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    
        #AllowOverride All
        #Allow from all
        #Require all granted

or this

DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/Zend/workspaces"
    ServerName local-portail.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    
        #AllowOverride All
        #Allow from all
        #Require all granted

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: yes , but it doesn't change. it is possible to restore original httpd.config without reinstallation  wamp?

Comment: I thing there is no way to restore it without any subversion programm.
 but here is an explaination how to rebuild your wamp without loosing data http://flowingmotion.jojordan.org/2013/07/19/12-steps-to-rebuild-your-wamp-server-without-losing-your-data/

Answer (score 0):

Is this the section of httpd.conf that you changed?

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

If you want to make another directory the Directory root then a better way is to create a Virtual Host, or many virtual hosts, one for each project.

See this post for how to do that. Ignore the title, it is a post that describes how to setup Virtual Hosts. [Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)